# How do I shutdown a socket properly that is streaming webcam footage?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, opencv, python

I am trying to stream my laptops webcam stream to my pc for cv2 manipulation. The stream works but I am not really sure how to go about closing the socket.

I don't have a webcam on my desktop so I wanted to try and stream my laptops webcam over to learn cv2 on the footage. I am new to sockets, I went through the documentation and did a bunch of googling to get this far, even though most of what I now have was copy pasted. I am not really sure where to look to learn how to shut down sockets propery when streaming video data with cv2.
I've tried using with socket.socket( ... ) as s: to close the connection
breaks after the while and try loops, that go into shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR and close() and I've tried terminating the program on both the client and server.

```
    #server.py

    import socket
    import cv2
    import pickle
    import struct
    def main():
        HOST=''
        PORT=12397    
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            print('Socket created')
            s.bind((HOST,PORT))
            print('Socket bind complete')
            s.listen(10)
            print('Socket now listening')
            conn,addr=s.accept()

            data = b""
            payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
            while True:
                try:
                    key = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
                    while len(data) < payload_size:
                        data += conn.recv(4096)
                        if key == ord("q"):
                            print("Socket closed.")
                            break
                    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
                    data = data[payload_size:]
                    msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
                    while len(data) < msg_size:
                        data += conn.recv(4096)
                        if key == ord("q"):
                            print("Socket closed.")
                            break
                    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
                    data = data[msg_size:]

                    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
                    frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    cv2.imshow('ImageWindow',frame)
                    cv2.waitKey(1)
                    if key == ord("q"):
                        print("Socket closed.")
                        break
                except:
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    break

        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        s.close()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

    #client.py

    import socket
    import cv2
    import pickle
    import struct
    def main():
        encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
            print('Connecting to socket.')
            client_socket.connect((ENTER IP HERE, 12397))
            connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
            print('Starting stream.')
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            cam.set(3, 320*2);
            cam.set(4, 240*2);
            frame_time = int((1.0 / 30.0) * 1000.0)
            img_counter = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    ret, frame = cam.read()
                    if ret:
                        result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
                        data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
                        size = len(data)
                        client_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
                        img_counter += 1
                        if cv2.waitKey(frame_time) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break
                    else:
                        break
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
        cam.release()
        client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        client_socket.close()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I want to close the connection by pressing q.
I currently get WinErrors on the server
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
and on the client
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
when I (spam) "q" on the server side, it doesn't seem to catch if I just press it once.

Answer (score 0):

That error typically happen if you use the socket *after* you have closed it.

Now if we take your server, you do something like

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    ... code here ...

s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
s.close()
```

That means the `shutdown` and `close` calls are done *after* the socket have already been closed.

You have the same problem in the client program.

Comment: He already called shutdown and close in his program. How is your solution different from his?

Comment: @T-Dog I *don't* show a solution, but it can be implied from the answer (remove the explicit `shutdown` and `close` calls).